# Django Toggling MultiDB and Installed Apps in settings.py

Tags: python, django, list, tuples

I have a set of apps and multiple databases that are only needed during initial setup.  I want to toggle this as needed so I setup a constant IMPORT_MODE in settings.py.

To make this work, I changed INSTALLED_APPS from a tuple to a list.  That way I can add the list of apps I need when doing setup as needed.  There didn't seem to be any problems with this, but I guess this opens that up to the possibility of the list of INSTALLED_APPS changing during run-time since it's no longer a tuple.

Is this a valid concern or should I just write a script to comment out the apps I don't need in the INSTALLED_APPS tuple instead?

However small, does having to check if we're in INSTALL_MODE or not affect performance at all?  Or does Python make this essentially do away with that check when it's making the pyc?  (Not sure if that last question makes sense to people or not.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter no. You might want to consider doing something like this though, which is a Django idiom I've seen (and use). Define your alternate settings in another module (say import_mode.py) and import them, overriding the default settings but only when the module containing your alternate settings is importable.

```
try:
    from import_mode import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```